# Postgresql syntax error at or near "pg_ctl"

Tags: postgresql

When I run the command **pg_ctl status** on remote server running postgresql version 9.4.11, 
I get this error message:

```
{ [error: syntax error at or near "pg_ctl"]
  name: 'error',
  length: 87,
  severity: 'ERROR',
  code: '42601',
  detail: undefined,
  hint: undefined,
  position: '1',
  internalPosition: undefined,
  internalQuery: undefined,
  where: undefined,
  schema: undefined,
  table: undefined,
  column: undefined,
  dataType: undefined,
  constraint: undefined,
  file: 'scan.l',
  line: '1053',
  routine: 'scanner_yyerror' }
```

I want to get the info if server is up or not.

Comment: pg_ctl is an OS command (binary), not an SQL command or function. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pg-ctl.html

Comment: @wildplasser oh, then is there any SQL command I can use to find the server status? I tried SHOW ALL but it has server version but no server status

Comment: Well, if it reacts,it is probably running ;-) Maybe: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/monitoring.html

Comment: Have a look at [`pg_isready`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pg-isready.html).